# How to correctly maintain SSOT (Single Source Of Truth) in database?

Tags: database, postgresql, relation

i am new to database, i come from Front End world and in it i really appreciate SSOT. After all, i don't want to see a 'weird' stuff happening on the UI as it can affect user's behavior.

Now that i design my own backend using postgres, i am really having difficulties on deciding how to approach SSOT.

Let's say i have 5 tables. `user`, `order`, `order_status`, `payment` and `payment_cancellation`.

The relation is:

- `user` - `order` : 1-n
- `order` - `order_status` : 1-n
- `order` - `payment` : 1-n
- `payment` - `payment_cancellation` : 1-1

`order_status` have `status` column which is an `ENUM('UNPAID', 'PAID', 'CANCELLED')`.

**First question**:
Isn't the `order_status` table completely redundant? Since i can derive the `order_status.status` column completely from whether the `order` table have any relation to `payment` or not, right? Consider these scenario:

- `UNPAID` = order that has no payment
- `PAID` = order that have any payments
- `CANCELLED` = order that have any payments whose last payment has payment_cancellation

**Second question:**
Wouldn't i break the *SSOT* by having `order_status` table? Since if i am not correctly handling any relation change, then the data wouldn't be valid anyway?

**Third question:**
BUT, if i do not have `order_status` table, then i would need to join many tables just to be able to retrieve the final status. Are there any suggestion for this?

Thank you so much for reading and answering.

Comment: Maybe order_status can change over time,  and you want to keep history?

Comment: Yet because order can have multiple payments, I can have that too without order_status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think hard about the naming of things. The values UNPAID, PAID, and CANCELLED seem to deal with different things. For example, it's one thing to cancel an order. It's a completely different thing to cancel a payment. Think hard about the kinds of things you need to know the status of: bills, orders, payments, invoices, etc.

Second, in the database world, we don't talk about *single source of truth* as much as we talk about normalization. I've see preoccupation with SSOT and DRY (don't repeat yourself) lead application programmers down horribly bad paths.

Finally, you probably don't need the order_status table. (But that's application-dependent.) Normalization itself doesn't mean you need to join many tables to retrieve the final status. But using surrogate ID numbers in every table does.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of depth in your answer my noob mind just cannot process well. Could you please elaborate more on your answer? I am interested on the 'bad paths' you mentioned. Maybe by knowing the bad paths i should avoid, I could see how to approach this problem

Comment: Second, how is it that "you probably don't need order_status" is application dependent?

Comment: @AndreeChristian: "order_status" isn't necessary if you can derive every column from other data, but that has performance implications. In real-world accounting, payments don't have a one-to-one correspondence with orders, and you might want to know whether an order has shipped, has been delivered, etc. "Shipped" and "Delivered" reflect the status of either an order or a shipment, depending on your application. If you use an order_status table, you also need code to keep the status right when supporting data changes. Also, you might want to know *when* an order was canceled.